# How do I tie this program that validates passwords together? I keep getting error messages and when I fix those errors, more pop up

Tags: java, static-methods

All I need is for this program to check both inputs and print either, "The passwords do not match", "The password is not valid", or "The password is valid"

/**
This program asks for a password, then asks again to confirm it.
If the passwords don't match or the rules are not fulfilled, prompt again.
-The password must be at least 8 characters long.
-The password must have at least one uppercase and one lower letter.
-The password must have at least one digit.
*/

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class PasswordCheck {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        do {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a password:");
        String pass1 = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Confirm password:");
        String pass2 = in.nextLine();
        
        if(samePassword(pass1,pass2)) {
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The passwords do not match");
        }
        
        if(validate(pass1)) {
            System.out.println("The password is valid");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The password is not valid");
        }
        while(validate == false);
    }
    /**
            Checks if both passwords are the same
            @param password and confirmation password
            @return true or false
        */
    public static boolean samePassword(String password, String confPassword) {
        
        boolean isSame = password.equals(confPassword);
        
        if(isSame == true) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    /**
            Checks if the password is valid.
            It uses isDigit(), isLowerCase(), and isUpperCase() helper methods.
            @param the password
            @return true or false
        */
    public static boolean validate(String password) {
        
        String thePassword = password;
                
        for(int i = 0; i < thePassword.length(); i++) {
            
            if(i >= 8) {
                if(isDigit(thePassword.charAt(i)) == true)
                    if(isLowerCase(thePassword.charAt(i)) == true)
                        if(isUpperCase(thePassword.charAt(i)) == true)
                            return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    /**
            Checks if the character is a digit (0 to 9).
            @param a character.
            @return true or false.
        */
    public static boolean isDigit(char ch) {
        
        char aCharacter = ch;
        if(aCharacter >= 0 && aCharacter <= 9) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    /**
            Checks if the character is lower case(a to z).
            @param a character.
            @return true or false.
        */
    public static boolean isLowerCase(char ch) {
        
        char aCharacter = ch;
        if(Character.isLowerCase(aCharacter)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    /**
            Checks if the character is uppercase (A to Z).
            @param a character.
            @return true or false
        */
    public static boolean isUpperCase(char ch) {
        
        char aCharacter = ch;
        if(Character.isUpperCase(aCharacter)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Formatted the code & fixed some typos and commented where ever needed. Please test it now.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PasswordCheck {
    /**
     * Checks if both passwords are the same
     *
     * @param password and confirmation password
     * @return true or false
     */
    public static boolean samePassword(String password, String confPassword) {

        boolean isSame = password.equals(confPassword);

        if (isSame == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the password is valid.
     * It uses isDigit(), isLowerCase(), and isUpperCase() helper methods.
     *
     * @param password
     * @return true or false
     */
    public static boolean validate(final String password) {

        boolean hasDigit = false, hasUppercase = false, hasLowercase = false;
        /*for (int i = 0; i < thePassword.length(); i++) {

            if (i >= 8) {
                if (isDigit(thePassword.charAt(i)) == true)
                    if (isLowerCase(thePassword.charAt(i)) == true)
                        if (isUpperCase(thePassword.charAt(i)) == true)
                            return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }*/
        for (Character ch : password.toCharArray())
            if (isDigit(ch))
                hasDigit = true;
            else if (isLowerCase(ch))
                hasLowercase = true;
            else if (isUpperCase(ch))
                hasUppercase = true;
        return hasDigit && hasLowercase && hasUppercase;
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the character is a digit (0 to 9).
     *
     * @param ch character.
     * @return true or false.
     */
    public static boolean isDigit(char ch) {

//        char aCharacter = ch;
//        if (aCharacter >= 0 && aCharacter <= 9) {
//            return true;
//        } else {
//            return false;
//        }
        return Character.isDigit(ch);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the character is lower case(a to z).
     *
     * @param ch character.
     * @return true or false.
     */
    public static boolean isLowerCase(char ch) {

//        char aCharacter = ch;
//        if (Character.isLowerCase(aCharacter)) {
//            return true;
//        } else {
//            return false;
//        }
        return Character.isLowerCase(ch);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if the character is uppercase (A to Z).
     *
     * @param ch character.
     * @return true or false
     */
    public static boolean isUpperCase(char ch) {

//        char aCharacter = ch;
//        if (Character.isUpperCase(aCharacter)) {
//            return true;
//        } else {
//            return false;
//        }
        return Character.isUpperCase(ch);
    }

    ////////////Main////////////
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var out = System.out;
        boolean validPassword = false;
        do {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            out.println("Enter a password:");
            String pass1 = in.nextLine();
            out.println("Confirm password:");
            String pass2 = in.nextLine();
            out.println(pass1 + " " + pass2);

            if (samePassword(pass1, pass2)) {
            } else {
                System.out.println("The passwords do not match");
            }

            if (validate(pass1)) {
                System.out.println("The password is valid");
            } else {
                System.out.println("The password is not valid");
            }
            //validating password
            validPassword = validate(pass1) && samePassword(pass1, pass2);
        } while (!validPassword);//while password is invlaid keep

    }
}
```

### Output:

```
Enter a password:
blabla@123
Confirm password:
blabla@123
blabla@123 blabla@123
The password is not valid
Enter a password:
Blabla@123
Confirm password:
Blabla@123
Blabla@123 Blabla@123
The password is valid
```

Comment: It allows me to compile and run but tells me "The password is not valid" when it should be valid.

Comment: Yes its because the logic which you have provided inside validate is wrong I have fixed it please run it again.

Comment: Ok, everything is fixed now. This was one of my tougher projects so far, so I really appreciate the guidance.